# passing token at every request with web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

First of all, I think identity over HTTP has become a nightmare to understand, even worse to implement and just to make it clear, I think there are too many options.

I sound like someone who didn't get it, I know...

Anyways...

I have implemented a token provider and it gives me tokens when I hit an endpoint (/token). This is my access token and now I need to understand how I should store this for subsequent requests to the actual API.

Could I store in a session ?

And next, do I need to pass on my access token to the API for every request ?

I am fairly (totally) new to token based authentication but have patience, I will get there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to send your token with each request in the Authorization Header using Bearer scheme, regarding storing the token, OAuth 2.0 gives you the full responsibility on how to store the token, so if you are building SPA or Server Web APP you can store it in local storage or cookie and read the value from there and send it with each request.

I recommend you to read my blog post which should clarify all the ambiguity
[Token based Authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)